# Reduce the vertical space between the title and the main body

Tags: document-classes, report, vertical-spacing

I am using this template:
and I want to reduce the space between the "Abstract" as a title and the main body of the abstract as shown in the screenshot included. The abstract is included separately in the destination: ./chapitres/resume/abstract; as it is clearly shown from the code; [[image: Vertical space between "Abstract" and the the first entry of the text][1]][1]

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\huge}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{20pt}[0pt]
\usepackage{acronym}
\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{14}{16}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{13}{13}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{12}{12}}

%\titleformat{\chapter}%[display]
%{\normalfont\chapfnt\scshape}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\chapfnt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\secfnt\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\ssecfnt\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\ssecfnt\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection} {0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
%\usepackage{xspace}

%\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.12,0.47,0.87}


%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % alignement image

%\synctex=1
%%%%%%%%% interligne 1.5
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
%\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% bibliographie par chapitre :
%     * mettre \bibliography et \bibliographystyle dans chaque fichier inclu
%\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
%ajouté

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%[left=3.2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

% permet de faire une table des matières par chapitre
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{color}
% ajoute (entre autre) la bibliographie dans la table des matières
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array, diagbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}

%\cleardoublepage

%\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
%\usepackage{ntheorem}
%\theoremstyle{plain}
%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{lem}{Lemme}[section]
%\newtheorem{cory}{Corollaire}[section]
%\theoremstyle{definition}
%\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Définition}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{verbatim}


%\usepackage{multirow}

% style de numérotation
\usepackage{engrec}
%\usepackage{a4++}
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\thepart{\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@table}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@equation}
\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}.}
%profondeur de numérotation
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}%pour la numérotation dans le corps du document
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%fancy
%\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{}

%Ajouter des entete au chapitre non numeroté
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1]{\chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markboth{\slshape\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\slshape\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
%\markboth{\slshape{#1}}{\slshape{#1}}}

%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textbf{\chaptername\ 
                %   \thechapter. #1}{}}}

\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %Conny

\ChTitleUpperCase \ChTitleAsIs \ChNameAsIs
%\ChNameLowerCase \ChTitleLowerCase \ChNameVar{\centering\Huge\rm\bfseries}
\ChNumVar{\Huge} \ChRuleWidth{2pt} \ChTitleVar{\centering\Huge}




%lien hypertex
\usepackage{hyperref} % Créer des liens et des signets
\hypersetup{    
    colorlinks=false, %colorise les liens
    breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs
    urlcolor= blue, %couleur des hyperliens
    linkcolor= blue,    %couleur des liens internes
    citecolor=blue, %couleur des références
    %pdftitle={Rapport de stage}, %informations apparaissant dans
    %pdfauthor={Anonyme}, %les informations du document
    %pdfsubject={Simulation}    %sous Acrobat.
}
% biblio ordonnee classique
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}


%\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemme}[chapter]
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothèse}[chapter]

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{natbib}  % 
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}





%**********************************************************
%\newcommand\chapterstring{Chapitre}
%
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%
%% chapitres
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\bfseries\sffamily\color{Blue4}} {\filright
%   \enspace \Large \chapterstring~\thechapter} {14pt} {\Huge\filcenter}
%
%% sections
%\titleformat{\section}{\vspace{0mm plus 2cm}\addpenalty{-1000}\color{Blue4}\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesection}{1em}{}
%[{\color{Blue4}\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
%
%% sous-sections
%\titleformat{\subsection}{\addpenalty{-500}\large\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesubsection}{1em}{} 
%
%% sous-sous-sections
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\penalty-500\vspace{0pt plus 2pt}{}\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesubsubsection}{}{}[\vspace{-14pt}]

%******************************
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{\textsc{Tableau}}}

% METTRE EQUATIONS EN GRAS
%\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\begingroup\bfseries\mathversion{bold}#1\endgroup}
\raggedbottom


\begin{document}
%   \thispagestyle{empty}% enlever numéro de page

%       \end{tabular}
\pagestyle{fancy}
        % le titre
        %\maketitle
        % preparation des minitocs
        \dominitoc
        %\onehalfspacing
        %\pagenumbering{arabic}
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        
        %%%%%% Abstract
        \begingroup
        \def\MakeUppercase#1{#1}
        \include{./chapitres/resume/abstract}
        \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to edit my question. If it is now more clear I hope to get a help from you!